# Recebendo diversos valores de TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textbox

Preciso editar simultaneamente vários registros, mais especificamente uma lista de alunos e carregar/editar a partir de diversas `textbox`s vinculadas a tal.

Basicamente preciso dar/tirar presença dos mesmos.

Como poderia proceder?

Comment: Acho que você deveria quebrar sua pergunta em várias perguntas, pois existem várias etapas envolvidas na sua pergunta em questão, é difícil saber exatamente onde está sua dúvida. Vide exemplo a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a lista de alunos estiver no modelo que você passa para a view pode usar um `EditorFor`... não sei como está o seu modelo, então vou supor uma estrutura como abaixo:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Alunos.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Alunos[i].Nome)
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT**

Supondo uma classe de modelo chamada `Aluno`:

```
public class Aluno
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Você pode criar um controller, com actions chamadas `EditMany` para GET e POST:

```
public ActionResult EditMany()
{
    var alunos = db.Alunos.ToArray();
    return View(alunos);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditMany(Aluno[] alunos)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(alunos);

    try
    {
        // TODO: editar cada um dos alunos no banco de dados
        // supondo que esteja usando o entity framework:
        foreach (var aluno in alunos)
            db.Entry(aluno).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(alunos);
    }
}
```

E uma view chamada `EditMany.cshtml`, que recebe uma lista de Alunos:

```
@model IList<Mvc3Application.Models.Aluno>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Many";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Alunos</legend>
        @for (var i = 0; i < this.Model.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Nome)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Nome)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Nome)
            </div>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: E como eu recupero esses dados no Controller? Meu maior problema é tratar a recepção dos dados.

Comment: Basta receber na action do controller o mesmo tipo passado para a view.

Comment: Vou fazer um exemplo aqui e já posto.

Comment: Ai está o exemplo amigo... espero que isso te ajude.

Comment: Obrigado ! Funcionou.